# Typing event support in Microsoft Bot Framework WebChat

Tags: botframework

Is it the typing event supported in the Microsoft Bot Framework WebChat?

If it is, then how many seconds it is visible to show typing event 
and in which form is it showing typing bubble or text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typing is supported in the [Microsoft Bot Framework WebChat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) as you can see [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/search?q=Typing&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93) and [here](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/channel-inspector/channels/WebChat?f=Typing&e=example1). I believe that it shows an animated GIF per this [PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/pull/296/files).

Comment: https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/channel-inspector/channels/Email?f=Channeldata&e=example1